# Is there an python function for splitting the dataset into training, validation and testing?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a directory containing all data for training, testing and validation, but the data is inside a directory, for example:

1. Directory

   - 01

     - Image001.png
     - Image002.png
     - Image003.png
     - Image004.png
   - 02

     - Image001.png
     - Image002.png
     - Image003.png
     - Image004.png
   - ...

     - ...
   - 29

     - Image001.png
     - Image002.png
     - Image003.png
     - Image004.png

Where 01 is the label and Image001 ... Image004 is the training / testing / validation image.

Is there any tensorflow function to split my dataset into training, testing and validation?

I've tried:

```
data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(preprocess_input)
train_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
                                        directory='../input/',
                                        target_size=(image_size, image_size),
                                        batch_size=10,
                                        class_mode='categorical')
```

What does I need to split?

Comment: You need to make a separate folder for train, test and validation for using this class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want  to only separate the data into training and validation then you can use validation split parameter in ImageDataGenerator. When creating the training and validation generator you can pass subset ='training /validation' and pass same directory for both validation and training. You can check here  [Training with validation split](https://kylewbanks.com/blog/train-validation-split-with-imagedatagenerator-keras)

For testing purpose you have to keep a separate directory.